# ViewController.type does not have a member named

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var answer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var maxNum: UITextField!

let min = minNum.text.toInt()
```

I'm getting the error: ViewController.Type does not have a member named 'minNum'
How do i fix this error? (I'm new to programming)

I' using Xcode 7 beta 2

Answer (score -1):

is that `min` assignment just floating?

Put that line inside your viewDidLoad, or inside the `textFieldDidEndEditing` function. Looks like you're trying to assign the value of a text field that doesn't exist, since it hasn't been instantiated yet.

(I wrote an answer before i realized there's not actually a question here..)